Would superstrong but stupid giants be particularly useful in premodern economies?
Said giants look like stereotypical Orcs, about 8-10 feet tall and with immense upper body strength. As in, they can lift around a ton over their head and hold it there for 5-10 minutes. However, they are incapable of following any more than the simplest instructions. For example, you can mime swinging an axe at them and tell them to do so to a tree, but they'll need to be told when to stop swinging and to start swinging at another tree after one is done.
They aren't particularly aggressive unless attacked or otherwise provoked.
The economy in question is premodern, as in still using watermills and muscle power. Muscle power of both humans and animals. And even the watermills are a rare thing used only in the most prosperous regions.
Will these Orcs, presuming they eat about as much as the average horse or donkey, be a good investment for agriculture or other major premodern industries?

Do they eat the same things as a horse?

??? Pre-modern economies used oxen on a very large scale to power vehicles and agricultural implements. Oxen are the canonical illustration of very powerful but quite dim. Are those orcs any stupider than oxen? (And saying that something eats about as much as "a horse or donkey" is not informative at all. Donkeys are much smaller than horses, and moreover they are desert animals which can live on marginal lands where horses would not survive.)

@gs Yes, they can subsist on just hay or oats.

Just a small point in the nature of a minor frame challenge for you, if they're bigger than us, there is actually no reason to suppose that they should be dim, their brain can be proportionately smaller than ours and still every bit as big (or bigger come to that) than ours, intelligence is about the number of neurons and their connections, brain to body size ratio is irrelevant and long debunked as the pertinent statistical measure to use as a rule of thumb for likely IQ .. they can be geniuses.

VTC:Too Story-Based. They will if you write your story that way. They won't if you don't. There is no right answer to this question. Per the [help/dont-ask], "Some subjective questions are allowed, but 'subjective' does not mean 'anything goes.'" Considering elephants, oxen, and other large animals have proven to be good investments for muscle-power workforce, why are you worried about the issue? What's the real problem?

@JBH You're right.

@Pelinore to be fair EQ is pretty useful for general information for larger clade level diffrence in animals, just not great for detailed comparision of closely related species.

So a humanoid race basically built to be unable ot care for themselves, this may cause more problems for you then you realize. this is going to draw up a lot of comparison to jusifications made for historic slavery.

@John With a little luck, a good part of the story addresses exactly that while addressing questions like, "where do you draw the line between an acceptable beast of burden and slavery?" "When does using a beast of burden become animal abuse?" "How are a society's mores reflected in a transsocietal relationship when one of the societies is just cognitive enough to know abuse when it experiences it?" Honestly, there's a lot of good that could come from a story based on this idea. "When is employing the mentally disabled a kindness and when is it exploitation?"

@JBH, possibly, although using premodern times may hamper that since actual slavery of humans was common, outgroup empathy was less common , and religious justification was often also common. But I was just pointing out the potential issue to the OP, because I'm not going to presume what kind of story they are writing.

I'm sorry @John but what do you think EQ stands for? .. I only know EQ as "emotional quotient" (which is frankly a load of complete bollox from a bunch of very ignorant people) but that however doesn't scan as what you meant when what you're responding to is factored in, hence the query.

You need to answer 3 things, can they pull a plow or wagon? that is a  large part of agricultural work, Upper body strength can't actually do much good on a farm if they are that dumb, why do they do what humans want? and how are they both smart enough to easily imitate movments and so dumb they don't get simple goals. the former is a much harder mental task than the latter. using somthing completely non-biological like golems might be easier to justify behaviorally.

@Pelinore encephalization quotient https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encephalization_quotient#:~:text=Encephalization%20quotient%20(EQ)%2C%20encephalization,a%20range%20of%20reference%20species.

@John Aha! Cheers, I don't need the link just 'encephalization', I can extrapolate from there ;)

@Pelinore, to me its a really common biological term, so I didn't know how much biological terminology you knew so included the link, also for everyone else.  But I am probably biased, jargon wise, becasue EQ is used a lot in paleontology for evolutionary changes.

@John it is, though depending on the circles you've been moving in most recently perhaps, as soon as I saw the word I knew it, I'm just so used to hearing made up junk science twits using that abbreviation to mean emotional quotient that I forgot it has a real worthwhile meaning attached to it is all [shrugs] ;)

@John Because they're alchemical products. Robots made of flesh and magic. That's why they do as humans tell. But since they're not very advanced, their intellect is lesser than an orangutan than a human.

I would say so
There are plenty of jobs pre-mechanization that require brute force over ignorance.
Having the ability to manipulate tools (in a way that horses or oxen cant) is a huge advantage.
Yes it might be frustrating for the Farmers to work out a system of how to get them to do what they want - but on the balance of things - this would be an asset.

What do the Orcs eat?
if they eat not just as much as a horse, but the same feed (grass) then they are essentially a slightly more useful horse. If they need to eat human food (grain, meat, vegetables etc) then they are less efficient than a horse, and thus, unlikely to be practical.
how good is their stamina?
For a work-animal, stamina is far more important than sheer strength. An Orc that can lift 1 ton for 5 minutes is moderately useful. But an Orc that can carry 200 kilograms for 10 hours is much, much more useful. The vast majority of premodern industries and farming required not incredible strength, but calorie-efficiency and stamina.
how durable are the Orcs?
Aside from their calorie intake, the most important aspect of a work animal is its ruggedness and health. Pre-modern world would have little to no veterinary knowledge, so the Orcs should be both very durable (not prone to injury even if they handle enormous weights) and highly resistant to disease, especially waterborne pathogens.
So lets make a generous assumption that your Orcs are stereotypical brute monsters: they can eat pretty much anything from grass to carrion, drink cesspool water with no issue, shrug off a 200kg rock falling on their heads, and can trek for miles carrying a whole cow. They have the iron stomach of a goat, the endless stamina of a camel, and the incredible durability that would make a rhino envious, plus enough enough rugged vitality to make a honey badger look like a dainty princess in comparison.
Thus, I could see uses as:

land reclamation. One of the hardest tasks of a pre-modern society was clearing the wilderness to make room for fields. It required cutting down countless trees, digging out the stumps, and turning the topsoil to get rid of weeds, rocks and debris. A very stupid, but infinitely patient and tireless Orc could do just that, with minimum supervision. This is functionally the same as an Orc going on a berserk rampage and tearing up the scenery, just slow and more deliberate.
digging. Be it moats, drainage ditches, wells, graves, or surface mines, an Orc could simply dig like a tireless giant dog. A bunch of Orcs could thus turn some piece of dry wasteland into green farmland by digging a network of trenches connecting to a river or a well.
carrying water. One of the most arduous and inefficient tasks for pre-modern humans was getting water to where it was needed. Water is very heavy, and a human carrying around buckets wastes almost as many calories as they gain from using said water for their farms and industries.
spinning thread. Another super boring and inefficient task. If the Orcs are sufficiently manually dexterous (or if they are given sufficiently oversized thread-spindles) they can just sit around and endlessly spin yarn.
Operating simple machinery: An orc can move a capstan, turn a mill axle, work giant bellows or a pump. As long as what is needed is simply "push this thing forever" or "slowly move this lever up and down", they should manage.
blacksmithing assistant: aside from the bellows, the Orc can (after a long period of training, for safety reasons) become a sledgehammer operator, endlessly slamming the same spot on the anvil while the blacksmith moves the piece under the blows.
shepherding. The smartest of Orcs could be tasked with being essentially shepherd dogs, helping to move the herds. Plus, even if the Orc is naturally a peaceful creature, Im sure it can be trained to protect the sheep from wolves etc with frightening efficiency. If the Orcs are truly strong enough to lift one ton, they should be strong enough to lift and yeet a Kodiak bear, or tear a wolf in half. Even if the Orc was truly docile and pacifistic, its sight alone would discourage most predators.
rowing. given the strength-per-size you granted your Orcs, it would only take 2 Orcs to push a longboat forward, and about 5 or 6 to move a merchant barge or a seagoing trading ship. Of course they would need constant supervision so that they would not crash the ship into an obstacle.
transport: there is no reason why your Orcs could not pull carts like a horse. Moreover they can also transport goods in giant, Orc-sized backpacks, or pairs of orcs transporting goods and people in litters. Atop of that, an Orc could effortlessly give a piggyback ride to a human. On a road, Orc transport might not be as fast or efficient as transport by a horse, but an Orc could easily trek through the wilderness, climb mountains, or trudge through swamps where a horse would be useless. An Orc with a litter-backpack for the humans and goods to sit on is pretty much the ultimate all-terrain vehicle.
warfare: you never mentioned if you want to use the Orcs for direct combat, so I would skip that, but consider that a herd of Orcs would make army logistics incredibly easier. even if the Orcs were 100% docile pacifists, they can still move tons upon tons of equipment, dig trenches, clear paths, raise palisades, move siege equipment etc.
disaster relief. The Orcs are likely too stupid to be easily scared, and and too durable to be easily damaged. You can send a herd of Orcs to pile sandbags against a flood, throw water at a fire, or carry out plague-victim corpses. They could even stop riots just by locking hands and forming a living wall around the rioters.
trade: as weird as it sounds, an Orc would be a good merchant in some circumstances. Order them to protect the merchandise at all costs, and only exchange one unit of merchandise for one coin of an exact type. The Orcs are too stupid and single-minded to fool, acting more like an intimidating vending machine that a merchant you can out-haggle.
finance. Finally, the Orcs themselves are a commodity. Each Orc is a big unit of estimated work-hours. In theory, as long as you have Orcs, you could file I-Owe-You notes exchangeable for days of Orc labor. As long as the estimated value of Orc labor is more or less constant, you can pay for stuff in Orc-dollars, take loans against the Orcs you own, rent Orcs for profit, or even trade Orc-shares on the open market. Small villages could pool their money to buy one Commons Orc to share. Merchants could rent Orcs for specific tasks. Orc breeders could make great money pimping-out their best Orc "studs". Orc races or Orc prize-fights could be bet against to the detriment of the gullible and gain of the wicked.


They're not pacifistic, they just won't start trouble unless provoked. The reason I didn't consider military uses is because I only designed them as industrial machinery. They're just not smart enough to be good as anything but pack mules for an army.

@Thales, I think you should lean on the pacifism angle anyway. An Orc smart enough to be a pack mule is smart enough to be a shock-troop. If it can chop trees, it can chop up people. If it can carry big rocks, it can just as well throw giant rocks at the enemy. Just make them very docile, or scared of violence, otherwise there is no reason why some clever general had not found a way to use them as weapons.

Several issues here:

If they are as stupid as you suggest, how do they learn languages well enough to follow orders?
Do they consume food in proportion to their strength, or are they using food more or less efficient than a bunch of humans? If they have the strength of ten humans, eat as much as ten humans, and need an overseer around the clock to keep them productive, they are probably not as as efficient as ten humans.
The horse got really significant in agriculture with the development of the horsecollar, which altered those "efficienty ratios" in favor of the horse. Your fictional orcs have hands to grip, which probably makes them more useful than a horse with the same strength.
How is the culture looking at them, as less intelligent humans or as bipedal animals? An old horse can be sold to the knackers. Doing the same to a slave would cause serious uproar is most societies.


They don't. All they understand is that the human wants them to imitate a basic action like swinging an axe. Anything more complex is beyond them. And no, I mentioned how much they eat, and it's about as much as a horse.

"If they are as stupid as you suggest, how do they learn languages well enough to follow orders?" Umm, that actually seems, quite dumb, as a potential point to make, dogs are stupid by human standards, and learn plenty of commands perfectly easily, horses and oxen are dumber than dogs (on average) and we have no problem training and making use of them either .. plus he seems to have your answer covered anyway with the bit about them following mimed commands, or has he edited since you wrote this?

The other two points are good though, perhaps more suited to comments than answers though?

@Thales, swinging an axe to fell a tree is actually skilled work, if you want the tree to fall cleanly and not just hammer the outer bark into pulp.

@Pelinore, dogs are mostly trained to do what dogs are good at, anyway, and even so it takes extreeme effort to go beyond "fetch" and "guard the herd." The training of most drug-sniffing dogs turns them into single-purpose search tools, for instance.
